# What does "Polarization Gradient Cooling" mean?

Tags: optics, laser, cooling

I'm well versed with what "Polarization Gradient Cooling" refers to, as in how the process works and what the term refers to, but the term itself baffles me. What is a "Polarization Gradient"?

The polarization, as is normally defined, is a vector. You take gradients (in the mathematical sense) of scalar-valued functions, not vector-valued ones. The literal interpretation of a "polarization gradient" seems undefined.

I'd believe it (after being somewhat disappointed) if the answer was just that the term shouldn't be taken so literally, and that by "polarization gradient" it is only meant that the polarization ($\sigma+, \sigma-, \pi$) is changing in space, but I was wondering if the term "polarization gradient" had some hidden meaning here that I was missing.

Comment: Do you have a link to a paper that contains this phrase in the context you're thinking of?

Comment: E.g. "Laser cooling below the Doppler limit by polarization gradients: simple theoretical models" by J. Dalibard and C. Cohen-Tannoudji".

Comment: I agree with you that 'gradient' is not being used in the mathematically precise sense- such is life. FWIW, I always preferred the term "Sisphyus cooling" anyway.

Comment: It seems that sisyphus cooling is a broader term than polarization gradient cooling, which refers to the specific case where you get the "always uphill" effect due to spatially varying polarizations.